# Python convert repeating lists into sublists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, recursion

I have multiple lists containing, e.g.

```
a = [['server_1', 'abc'], ['server_2', 'abc'], ['server_1', 'def']]
b = [['server_3', 'abc'], ['server_3', 'def'], ['server_4', 'abc']]
c = [['server_5', 'abc'], ['server_6', 'abc'], ['server_5', 'def']]
```

I'd like to transform the data into sub-lists, for example like below:

```
OUTPUT:
a = [['server_1', 'abc', 'def'], ['server_2', 'abc']]
b = [['server_3', 'abc', 'def'], ['server_4', 'abc']]
c = [['server_5', 'abc', 'def'], ['server_6', 'abc']]
```

What I want to do is single out the server names and add any sub-data that is attached with that list into a single element like shown above.

Any help is appreciated

I tried using multiple loops and if statements to compare the previous value in the list to the next one, but to no avail.
An attempt below:

```
   for part in repeating_list:      
      if part not in repeating_list:        
        new_list.append([part])      
      else:        
        pass (this should return it to sublist)
  return new_list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach is to use a `dict`, storing the first element as the key, then appending the 2nd element to the value as a list.

```
from collections import defaultdict

a = [['server_1', 'abc'], ['server_2', 'abc'], ['server_1', 'def']]

# Use a defaultdict to avoid testing for key in dict
data = defaultdict(list)
for item in a:
    data[item[0]].append(item[1])

# Convert to a list of lists, flattening the values
print([[k, *v] for k, v in data.items()])
```

> [['server_1', 'abc', 'def'], ['server_2', 'abc']]

Answer (score 3):

You can use `collections.defaultdict` to combine the sub-lists in one pass

```
from collections import defaultdict
a = [['server_1', 'abc'], ['server_2', 'abc'], ['server_1', 'def']]

def combine(my_list):
    result = defaultdict(list)
    for key, value in my_list:
        result[key].append(value)
    return [[key] + value for key, value in result.items()]

print(combine(a))
```

output

```
[['server_1', 'abc', 'def'], ['server_2', 'abc']]
```

Comment: @ShoaibNoorestani The codes from buran's answer and match's answer are almost identical. The main difference between the two is what happens if one of the lists has more than two elements. Try to execute both codes with `a = [['server_1', 'abc'], ['server_2', 'abc', 'suspicious third element'], ['server_1', 'def']]` and see how they differ.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution to your problem uses a two-pass approach. This means that we start with grabbing the names of the servers first. And in the second pass we can use the server to extract the data.

Here is the code that exemplifies this:

```
a = [['server_1', 'abc'], ['server_2', 'abc'], ['server_1', 'def']]
b = [['server_3', 'abc'], ['server_3', 'def'], ['server_4', 'abc']]
c = [['server_5', 'abc'], ['server_6', 'abc'], ['server_5', 'def']]


def solution(inp):
    servers: list[str] = []

    for x in inp:
        if x[0] not in servers: servers.append(x[0])

    output = []

    for server in servers:
        current_server_params = [server]
        for x in inp:
            if x[0] == server:
                current_server_params.extend(x[1:])
        output.append(current_server_params)

    print(output)


solution(a)
solution(b)
solution(c)
```

Output:

```
[['server_1', 'abc', 'def'], ['server_2', 'abc']]
[['server_3', 'abc', 'def'], ['server_4', 'abc']]
[['server_5', 'abc', 'def'], ['server_6', 'abc']]
```

Comment: Or just `servers = {x[0] for x in inp}`, using a `set` to remove duplicates much more efficiently. (Try it with a list `inp` of size 10000 and you'll see a noticeable difference in time of execution)

Comment: Also, you start your answer with the explanation *"A simple solution to your problem uses a two-pass approach."*, but your code actually does a lot more than two passes.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a keys list (`new_list_keys`) which can track index and can easily be checked if the key (`part[0]`) is already there. If it's not add part to `new_list` and the relevant key to keys list. If it is, concat rest of the list to the list at idx of the key

```
def solution(repeating_list):
  new_list = []
  new_list_keys = []
  for part in repeating_list:
    if part[0] not in new_list_keys:        
      new_list.append(part)
      new_list_keys.append(part[0])
    else:        
      idx = new_list_keys.index(part[0])
      new_list[idx]+=part[1:]
  return new_list

print(solution([['server_1', 'abc'], ['server_2', 'abc'], ['server_1', 'def']]))
print(solution([['server_3', 'abc'], ['server_3', 'def'], ['server_4', 'abc']]))
print(solution([['server_5', 'abc'], ['server_6', 'abc'], ['server_5', 'def']]))
```

Comment: Thank you, and a very good way of doing it without libraries.

Comment: @depperm if you need to check `if part[0] not in new_list_key` repeatedly, then you should use a `set`, not a `list`, for `new_list_key`. The operation `in` on a set is very efficient. The operation `in` on a list is rather inefficient.

Comment: @ShoaibNoorestani About your "without libraries" comment: if you dislike `from collections import defaultdict` and want to do it with a simple `dict` instead of a defaultdict, you can take buran's answer and replace `result = defaultdict(list); for key, value in my_list: result[key].append(value)` with `result = {}; for key, value in my_list: result.setdefault(key, []).append(value)`

Comment: @Stef but sets are unordered and matching index is important. That said I would actually go with dictionary